# how can secure my API call in flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, api, http, security

When using http package for API call. But HttpToolKit software get my api all information like headers, body and url. How can i hide all thing in flutter.[image: Example]

Comment: You can't. Don't make requests from the client that you expect to be private.

Comment: did not understand.

Comment: Thank God someone had finally asked this question. How come it is that easy to intercept an API call and fetch the headers that usually contain a secret key? And i still haven't come across a single proper solution to this problem! Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Salt in your api,

1. create function Encoder
2. use Api in function
3. create function to read api

example :

api : api.test.com

replace "a" -> "sjdruehuhdihyearoiu"
replace "p" -> "sj455453hbnddharoiu"

function to decode change this :
"sjdruehuhdihyearoiu" -> "a"

-----------------------or--------------------

add this package

```
 dependencies: crypto: ^3.0.1
       


import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  var dataToHash = 'api.test.com';

  var bytesToHash = utf8.encode(dataToHash);
  var md5Digest = md5.convert(bytesToHash);

  print('Data to hash: $dataToHash');
  print('MD5: $md5Digest');
}
```

**and send hash api to server and decode in server**